# Why is there no tag review queue?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, burninate-system

While it's been a long time with the current process of tag review and burnination, I think it should be obvious for everyone that the process is not effective.

There are [no burnination requests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest) on meta for the last 24 hours, while [almost a half](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=new) of recently added tags do not survive the "can you be an expert in [...]" test. The more time all of those tags will be available for users, the more questions will get there, and the more work on burnination will be required.

Worse, for every question with modified tags we get an extra task in edit review queue. Also there is either no way to do burnination as fast as reviews, or this system is so hidden that it's impossible to find. Burnination is just too hard.

I think it's time to finally admit that with the current approach this war is lost, and to start considering alternative solutions.

1. Could we have another review queue that asks:

   > Is it possible to be an expert in [...]? [ Yes ] [ No ]

   so that for [ No ] it should show a list of most common reasons like:

   - No experts in company name
   - No experts in abstract concepts
   - ...

   to filter out bad tags at the moment they get created?
2. Could we require a wiki for every created tag?
3. Could we have a review queue for tag wiki initial content and edits?

Comment: frankly, tags are too important to leave to 5 random reviewers.  The decision to burninate a tag should only happen after a lot of visibility and review

Comment: @psubsee2003 Why 5? The number could be much higher. If it's so important to make it public, items in this queue may go right into "hot" section. If it's so important to have yet another "sure, burn it with fire" answer on meta, automatically creating a meta post for each tag may be an option too. There is not so much discussion needed when you burn the tag with fire when there is only 1 question using it. You don't have to figure out alternative tags.

Comment: The whole tag expert thing is a bs measurement. See [When to burninate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/288751) for the actual metrics to be used to evaluate tags, and [What is the process for tag removal (burnination)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/4639281) for more information on the burnination process. It is getting much better than it once was, but generally we should avoid burnination wherever possible.

Comment: @TinyGiant This topic talks not about burnination process per se, but about the way to prevent it. As you properly pointed out, it's just bs measurement, and as such it allows to filter out bs without removing any good tags.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph It a bs measurement in that it should not be used as a measurement. In fact it is the worst possible measurement I can think of for evaluating tags. Evaluating tags using that measurement is only ever going to make the internet worse, not better. Please do not use that measurement to evaluate tags. The ability for someone to be an expert in a tag has no bearing on whether the tag should exist at all whatsoever. I don't know how to make it any clearer for you.

Comment: Relevant post https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387264/allow-users-to-review-newly-created-tags

Comment: _Is it possible to be an expert in [tag-here]_ This line is meaningless and it seduces too many people for the deletion of useful tags.

Comment: @weegee Your comment is meaningless and lacks argumentation.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph what if you can’t be an expert in a tag? You burninate it? NO thats not the only reason for burnination and the worst reason

Comment: To burninate a tag, you must meet certain conditions. Not just “Can’t you be an expert in this tag?” “No?”

Comment: People filter questions by tags, trying to get through the answers for their area of expertise. "Can you be an expert in [x]" is the most useful and simple condition.

Comment: There have been requests made of tags that would fit the no expert rule that have been denied because they can still be considered useful overall. One example would be the list tag.

Comment: There is already a privilege that is earned at 5k rep for approving tag wiki edits

Answer (score 2):

There already is a system in place that can help review new tags as they are created which is the moderator tools which is gained at 10k rep. On the stats page along with a list of the 10 (at least for the site where I have access to it) most recently created tags.

Users with this reputation level have the ability to monitor for new tags and take action on them as needed.

Another thing to note is if you have an acceptable question that just has a bad tag the person reviewing it has to decide what tag to replace it with which is a bigger responsibility than just reviewing the tag itself.

[untagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/untagged)

As it is there is already a surprising number of questions without a tag.

Answer (score -2):

Tags are too important to subject to a review of random users, which is a problem with the current review queues.

> There is no burnination requests on meta for the last 24 hours, while almost a half of recently added tags do not survive "can you be an expert in [...]" test.

So what, why is this that important to deal with immediately.  The review queues exist to deal with posts that request immediate attention.  Tags, while being critical for cataloging, do not have an immediate negative impact like bad question have, so they don't need a review queue to give them immediate attention.

Bad questions take up space and time.  They bump good posts off the front page, they waste valuable moderation time that could be spent answering questions.  But tags just exist in the background, so there is no need to deal with them immediately.

Review queues show a review to a very small number of people to get their opinion.  There is absolutely no way to get a significant community review/opinion from showing a tag to a small subset of the community.  While I don't have one the i can find right now, I've seen more than one tag burnination request that was turned around by someone providing a different opinion late in the process.   By putting this into a review queue, you look the same community oversight.

Simply put, bad tags are obscure enough to not diminish the quality of the site the moment they are created, unlike bad questions.  And tags are too important to subject to a random review of non-experts like the way the current review queues work.  The oversight from meta and the current burnination process is needed to prevent good tag deletion and to help remove bad tags with as much oversight and review as possible

Comment: Answers on meta are given by random users too. My topic has an explanation why tags require immediate attention.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph People complained about needing 5 reviews/votes for actions causing things to not get completed so how would increasing the number for this queue not cause problems?