# Allow users to review newly created tags

Tags: feature-request, tags

I'm sure that this has been asked before but I can't find any other dupe. It is an obvious FR.

Tags are used in questions to make the questions specific and other qualities that make it easier to answer and point. Anyone can create tags if their reputation is above 1500.

Most of the burnination requests I've seen are of ambiguous tags and overly broad ones and burninating them requires a big amount of work and cleanup.

If a new tag is created in a question by a user, let the reviewers and moderators know and let them review it to study its nature.

This solves two problems as far as I can see

- No more broad tags or ambiguous tags are created. So it is not late before the tag already has 500+ questions
- **New tags that are relevant and really serves the purpose deserves a good wiki**. The reviewers and moderators knowing that the new tag is created can also work on its wiki to welcome the new tag on the site

The reason I think this is relevant because this can save us a lot of *bad* tags and give a good wiki to relevant tags.

This is not for stray tags. But for the tags which are new and are getting popular day by day. Not the tags which only have 1 question or around that. That will be just the utter waste of time

Comment: Do you mean this page? https://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=new

Comment: @Dharman yes and a review queue for everyone to see the tag. And judge to remove it if it is bad or a new wiki to define the tag

Comment: I feel like it would be awfully difficult to judge if the tag is bad before seeing any questions use it.

Comment: Most tags don't benefit from this at all, and this would just be wasting the time of reviewers. A lot of the tags you're seeing that need burned have existed since the inception of the site, or close to it, back when tags were created for anything, we were still exploring what makes a good tag, and there were no restrictions on who could create a tag. They just never got cleaned up until now.

Comment: @animuson who knows what tags we are getting and some of the tags can be classified and judged by just looking at them. Tags are not created every day. This won't waste that much time

Comment: If 99% of the tags being created today are fine, then it's always wasting reviewer time, no matter how much of that time is actually needed. What's your evidence that we have a problem of crappy tags being created consistently and not being cleaned up?

Comment: I see the new tab and see all the crappy tags being created. Stackoverflow will be only populating and new tags will arise people will use them and the tag will get questions and thus it will stay. Else tags are just removed if they have no questions. I am not here to question _that we have a problem of crappy tags being created consistently and not being cleaned up_ I'm here to improve it @animuson

Comment: I'm looking at the new tab and most of the bad tags I see have already been removed through normal moderation - no review queue necessary.

Comment: @animuson This review queues will save tons of time as those actual time exhausting burnination requests will be saved from ever getting posted and the tag already being taken care of before it could populate

Comment: If you don't want to actually support your argument that this is a problem, then nobody is going to implement a new feature. We implement features to solve problems, not because people think they *might* be useful but don't really know.

Comment: @animuson I am trying as hard as I can to support my statements. If you put the future of StackOverflow in the front then it can really solve problems. Who knows that which tags is gaining population and at what time it could be a problem?

Comment: This gives new tags a wiki. New tags the direction and will save many people's time on meta. Simple reviewing will take care a lot of things. I can't romanticize things enough.

Comment: The new tag is not a problem until people start using it and abusing it.

Comment: @weegee The average user is not capable of creating a tag wiki for some random tag. That is something that requires someone who actually knows the details of the tag. A review queue would definitely *not* encourage users to create tag wikis for everything in the queue. We'd just end up with tons of really, really bad wikis.

Comment: @animuson Tags wikis are reviewed by default too If I'm not wrong. Bad ones won't arise. Tag wikis can be created by anyone (who is eligible) if the tag is on point and relevant. Else it can just pass the review queue to let the people decide on it

Comment: But if you're actively throwing every tag directly in front of users, you're just shifting a bunch more work into another queue that people now have to look at. I'll put it very bluntly: **Not every tag even needs a wiki.** We don't need to encourage users to create basic meaningless wikis for every single tag, simply because they'll get review credit for it.

Comment: Can you give an example of tags which don't have a wiki but are used widely? @animuson

Comment: What does that even matter? The two aren't related in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I somehow missed this post in the mass meta melee, but anyway better late than never. There *is* a "review" queue for tags too. Hidden in the concealed bottom corner of the already inconspicuous 10k tools, is the shiny queue called as 'New Tags':

> [image]

It was using this queue, that I figured out that [application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/application) was recreated, and filed a [new application for it to be burninated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388231/4099593). (There is also an userscript to help [see recreated tags](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/UserScripts/blob/master/SOShowBurninatedTags.user.js)).

Now, I know I disappointed you by calling thus a "review" queue, which is exactly why I put it in quotes. This is as good as a review queue as the 10k delete votes review queue, which is also tucked away in the 10k tools. The reason why I wanted to bring this out is because, I don't find many users visiting that page or using that tool. There is another advantage of this, I've used it to catch a particular user who was gaming for the Taxonomist badge. (Happened once in the past 3 years).

That said, I don't see a real need to bring this queue into the mainstream like the other queues. The other answers and comments on the post have already indicated several reasons why, and I agree with most of them.

Comment: That’ll do for a review queue for me. Hope it does help to select obselete tags

Comment: Also, that needs 10000 rep. I'll have to earn some for myself. :)

Comment: If that's a motivation to earn 10k reputation, then let it be!

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a need for adding new tag reviewing to the workload of the queues.

> [Quoting a comment] This review queues will save tons of time as those actual time exhausting burnination requests will be saved from ever getting posted and the tag already being taken care of before it could populate.

The easiest way to save time with burnination requests is [by not making them unless and until the tag is identified as causing actual harm](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/2751851).

> The reviewers and moderators knowing that the new tag is created can also work on its wiki to welcome the new tag on the site.

Reviewers in such a queue wouldn't be expected to have the domain-specific knowledge necessary to write an informative tag wiki that includes helpful usage guidance.

Comment: _Reviewers in such a queue wouldn't be expected to have the domain-specific knowledge necessary to write an informative tag wiki that includes helpful usage guidance._ They can provide wiki proposals to the people from the existing tags in the question. Like a javascript tag is tagged with a new tag or a new framework. So js people can write a wiki on them

Comment: @weegee How would the tag regulars get to consistently see the relevant proposals?

Comment: For instance a question tagged with javascript has a new tag and that question gets displayed to the people who are tag regulars. They will be asked to give the tag a wiki if relevant or else remove the tag and replace it with a relevant one.

Comment: "unless and until the tag is identified as causing actual harm" doesn't make any sense. It could have worked as well for questions and answers: if you don't like some bad answer, just ignore it, because it doesn't cause _actual harm_ to anyone. You've missed half of the criteria from that link.

Comment: The relevant things to link are "broken windows theory" and "Sisyphus rock".

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph Questions and answers have more visibility, and a larger effect on the usability of the site, than tags. Tags aren't enough of a problem to justify the costs of introducing a separate review queue for them.

Comment: So instead of a simple streamlined process of having a review queue we are using slow manual unstable process of creating a topic on meta. What kind of costs are you even talking about?

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph At a minimum, a review queue requires staff to implement and maintain it, and users to spend some of their time manning it. Besides that, some effort would have to go into managing undesirable side-effects of a review queue (such as roboreviewing, unjustified rejects, and bad tag wikis written by users unfamiliar with the relevant subject matter).

Comment: Implementation time is negligible compared to expected reduction in "manning" time. Robots on meta, lack of consensus on burnination and bad tag wikis are here right now.